# Is it possible to launch a .xlsm file from an asp .net page?

Tags: asp.net, epplus

I need to launch a .xlsm file from within an asp .net (VB) page. I tried a bunch of things, including EPPlus, but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked into using Microsoft.Office.Interop?

Comment: yes. That was my first stop. xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") does not work.

Comment: file is on a fileshare. not on the web server.

Comment: You may be running into permission issues, but you'd have to prove or disprove that thought. Here's an MSDN link to that regard: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/4297f8d7-3552-4e42-b00e-751b0764b5c2/

Comment: not a permission issue, but thank you for the link, I will try the suggestions posted on the link u shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! So, after two days of banging my head on the keyboard, this is what worked, I added code to the OnClientClick event as follows which launched the freaking .xlsm file!

OnClientClick="javascript: MyObject = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); MyObject.Run('file:///C:/MacroEnabledFile.xlsm')"

Comment: I'm sure your head is happy you figured it out. :)